# Jquery ajax URL changes with a # sign

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, authentication

I am new to JQuery in general. I am building a website using JQuery mobile and I am stuck on the login form. I am just trying to send username and password to PHP file.

When I enter a user name and a password, it directs me to the following link:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mainfolder/#/mainfolder/?username=abc&password=123&myLat=&myLon=
```

instead of:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mainfolder/php/login.php?username=abc&password=123&myLat=&myLon=
```

I wish if someone can help me. I am sorry but this is my first post on this site and I am having difficulties posting code :)

Thanks in advance.

The code is:

```
<form id="loginForm">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="username">username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" />
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="password">password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="myLat" id="myLat" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="myLon" id="myLon" value="">
    <input type="submit" id ="submit" data-role="button" data-inline="true" value="submit" />
</form>
<p><script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date());</script></p>
<div id="error"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#loginForm").submit(function(e)
            { 
                // stop form from submitting normally
                e.preventDefault();
                // clear error html
                $("#error").html('');

                dataString = $("#loginForm").serialize();

                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/php/login.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function() 
                    {
                        alert("success");
                        $("#error").html('submitted successfully');
                    },
                    error:function()
                    {
                    alert("failure");
                        $("#error").html('there is error while submit');
                    } 
                });
        });
    });         
    </script>
```

PHP code:

```php
<?php
    session_start();

    $username = $_post['username'];
    $password = $_post['password'];

?>
```

Comment: There is nothing in this code that should direct you to anything. The jquery should happen in the background and anyway, the method chosen is "post" so it should not affect the url in the address bar at all. What do you have in the login.php file?

Comment: do you have any javascript console errors when you start your application?

Comment: @Sylverdrag - i don't think it's a php problem here. he might be having javascript errors that makes jquery-ajax not running.

Comment: Do you have a router running somewhere? Have you included some other scripts like backbone or knockout?

Comment: Can you try passing the complete `url` to the ajax call. ie `http://www.mydomain.com/mainfolder/php/login.php`

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan If jquery-ajax is not running, then it should not redirect him. Method for passing variables is POST, so it should not affect the URL in the address bar at all, so most likely, there is some code we are not seeing which is causing the redirect.

Comment: The form is what redirecting him.

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? Try making your code standards complaint and try again. The "action" field is required in a form tag based on the w3 specs as far as I know. Even though this doesn't come into play here as you are using ajax it may be confusing the browser. So change your form start tag to:

```
<form method="POST" action="/mainfolder/php/login.php" id="loginForm">
```

Also change your script declaration to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

and see if that helps.

Edit: just confirmed the action field is required. See section 17.3
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried it on Safari and Firefox. As for the form tag, what you wrote is usually what I do but when I looked into the internet, developers are advising of eliminating method and action. It does not make sense to me. The script tag in w3school is left without the type parameter. What do you think?

Comment: @user1968651 please don't ever assume that w3shools are correct. They have many mistakes on their website and they have nothing to do with the actual w3 (http://www.w3.org). All script tags must have a type field as seen here: (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) see section 18.2.1.

Comment: after html5 release you can simply use <script></script> also in new browsers

Comment: @Peeyush thats correct in this case as long as the type is "text/javascript". If not the type attribute is still required.(http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element see section 4.3.1)